# Can we use ojdbc14.jar, classes12.jar with Oracle 12c and jdk1.5

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, oracle12c

We have upgraded our DB from 9 to 12c. I did not see ojdbc14.jar and classes12.jar. Does this mean we have to move to ojdbc5.jar, Ojdbc7.jar?

Comment: JDK 1.5 in 2016? Why don't you start by updating your JDK first?

Comment: Its old application and we cannot migrate to new at this time.

Comment: JDK 1.2 in 2016? Why?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name:- Its Jdk1.5. It is old application and we cannot migrate to 1.8 immediately.

Comment: See the FAQ [What are the various supported Oracle database version vs JDBC compliant versions vs JDK version supported?](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/jdbc-faq-090281.html#01_03)

Comment: ojdbc7.jar will work with Oracle 12c.

Comment: `classes12.jar` is for JDK 1.2, `ojdbc14.jar` is for JDK 1.4.

Comment: I know you've already said it twice, that you can't upgrade your JDK... but unfortunately that is the clear answer.   You are on thin ice as it is.  It is borderline irresponsible to not be at at least 1.7 by now.  I know from experience, the longer you wait, the worse it'll be.  The best time for you to upgrade is now, because 6 months from now it'll be even worse.

Answer (score 4):

You should strongly consider upgrading to JDK 8.  All earlier versions of Java have passed the end of their support life.  JDK 9 is coming.  It's time to upgrade.

The number in the Oracle JDBC JAR driver name refers to the JDK version it is written for.  classes12.jar is *hopelessly* out of date - that's JDK 1.2.

There's a good reason why Oracle isn't making classes12.jar and ojdbc14.jar available anymore.

It sounds like the best you can do is ojdbc7.jar.  Get the newest JAR you possibly can and use that.

Do yourself a favor and get your Java infrastructure up to date.  Using old Java with the latest Oracle version is like putting new wine in old wine skins.

Comment: I cannot migrate java version at this time. but i want to migrate the oracle version due to other related applications are migrating.

Comment: Yes you can.  You choose not to.  You'll have to accept the consequences of a bad choice.  Select the driver JAR that makes you happy.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue with my old legacy code.
I renamed the ojdbc8.jar as classes12.jar, and it is working great without any code migration.